# Bullseye test coverage plugin for Jenkins

Tags: c++, jenkins-plugins, bullseye

I am doing unit testing of C++ using gtest and using Bullseye coverage for test coverage.

I can see all results from Bullseye coverage.

But I want to create job on Jenkins and see all chart or graphical result on Jenkins. 
Is their any plugin or any suggestion for it?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just solved a similar quest, and here is a recipe I've used: http://howto.praqma.net/jenkins/bullseye

Comment: It is best not to post links without explaining what you are linking to, and how it solves the original problem.

Comment: The link is dead now. Could someone post the content or a new link?

Comment: @JedidiahBartlett I don't (yet) know an up-to-date link, but here's an archive version: https://web.archive.org/web/20180430090319/http://howto.praqma.net/jenkins/bullseye